# Is $(p)$ the same as $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, ideals

Suppose $p$ is a prime factor of $n$. We have $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of all integers mod $n$ and $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of all multiples of $p$ mod $n$, a prime ideal.

Is this exactly the same as $(p)$, just with different notation? Do the notations have different "meanings" in any way?

This is a very simple question, but I haven't found this laid out explicitly anywhere.

Comment: $(p)$ is the maximal ideal in $\mathbf Z$ generated by $p$ and $p\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is the maximal ideal in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ generated by the congruence class $p+n\mathbf Z$. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Bernard Doesn't $(r)$ have a meaning for any ring $R$ with $r\in R$? I.e. if it's made clear that the context is the quotient ring and not $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't $(p)$ a maximal ideal of the quotient ring?

Comment: No, it is $(\overline{p})=(p+n\Bbb Z)$, this is a difference. Here $p$ is in $\Bbb Z$, but $\overline{p}$ is a coset in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Could you briefly explain what the "addition" means here? I would expect $(p+n\mathbb{Z})$ to involve multiples of $n$, not multiples of $p$.

Comment: $Z/nZ$ is a group whose elements are subset of $Z$ of the form $a+nZ = \{ a+nc,c\in Z\}$ for each $a\in Z$ and the group law is $(a+nZ)+(b+nZ) = \{ u+v, u\in a+nZ, v\in b+nZ\} = a+b+nZ$. It is also a ring with the multiplication $(a+nZ)(b+nZ) = \{\sum_j u_jv_j, u_j\in a+nZ, v_j\in b+nZ\}=ab+nZ$.

The group definition works fine for $pZ/nZ$ whose elements are subsets of $Z$ and also elements of $Z/nZ$.

The subgroup of $Z/nZ$ generated  by $p+nZ$ is $0+nZ,p+nZ,(p+nZ)+(p+nZ),\ldots$ which is also $pZ/nZ$ and it is also a (prime and maximal) ideal (ie. a subgroup closed under multiplication).

Comment: In a commutative ring with unity if $a\in R$ then $a\Bbb{Z}$ is the smallest subgroup containing $a$ and $ \langle a \rangle =aR= \{ \sum_j r_j  a, r_j\in R\}$ is the smallest ideal containing $a$.

Comment: I see, I'm not as familiar with the additive coset notation. That makes sense to me now. All together these comments would constitute an answer I think.